# Unbounded function with uniform bounds on Integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

I'm looking for examples of unbounded functions $f\colon\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ with the property that for all $L$ exists some $C(L)$ with 
$$\int_x^{x+L} f(t)dt \le C$$
for all $x$.

Comment: $f(n)=n$, $n$ an integer. $f(x)=0$, otherwise.

Comment: Okay, I should have said smooth or at least continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can choose $f$ non-negative, continuous, integrable and unbounded, for example 
a piecewise linear function for which $f(k)=k$, $f(k-2^{-k})=f(k+2^{-k})=0$.

Instead of a continuous function, one can choose a smooth one, scaling adequately a bump function in order to get a smooth non-negative integrable bounded function.

In these cases $C$ will not depend on $L$.